# Excel Macro for Converting names to emails

Tags: excel, vba

I know some parts of this question have been asked before but I'm trying to make this a "one-stop-shop" macro. I frequently have lists of names (first, last). I need to take those names and create emails based on the company naming convention.

For example:

- FirstLast@company.com
- F.Last@company.com
- FLast@company.com

My macro has the InputBox-es to ask for both the format of the naming convention and the company domain. I'm not a VBS expert so I would like some help. Here is what I have so far. This is a small excerpt of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
Sub email()
    Dim format
    format = Application.InputBox("Set Email Format", "Format", "first.last", Type:=2)
    Dim fqdn
    fqdn = Application.InputBox("Enter Email Domain", "Domain", Type:=2)


    If format = "first.last" Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=RC[-2]&'.'&RC[-1]&fqdn"
    ElseIf format = "flast" Then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=CONCATENATE(LEFT(RC[-2],1), RC[-1], fqdn)"
    End If
End Sub
```

One of the problems is adding the fqdn variable into the formula. The other problem I'm having is I keep getting a "Run-time error '1004': Method 'FormulaR1C1' of object 'Range' failed" error when I try to run it. Can't seem to find the root cause. I've tried adding Range values but nothing I've tried is working.

Comment: Try `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = =RC[-2] & "." & RC[-1] & "fqdn"`.

Comment: Didn't work. "Compile error: Expected: end of statement"  (highlighting the period on the first formula.

Comment: Might be more user friendly to use checkboxes to determine format?

Comment: I agree @findwindow I might try that later. For now, I would like to get a working macro and this would be the easiest way (that I know of)

Comment: The ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 method expects a Range object. I just don't know how to add it in. I looked up a lot of info about it but couldn't find anything that worked. I would like the macro to go through all of the sheet to make the changes. Some lists have 50 users, some 500.

Comment: @BruceWayne It's still giving me the compile error. (Expected end of statement. Now at the RC[-2])

Comment: My last suggestion: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&"".""&RC[-1]&""fqdn"""`.  If that doesn't work, write your formula in a cell (regular format), then go to Options --> Formula, and click "R1C1 Style". Then record a macro, select your cell with the formula, and hit "ENTER" to re-enter the formula. Then take a look at the code generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see what you want to do,
make a function instead

```
    Function email(firstName As String, lastName As String, convention As String,domain As String)
    'domain = "@company.com"
    'convention values : firstlast, flast, f.last

      Select case convention 
           Case "firstlast" 
               email = firstName & lastName & domain 
           Case "flast"
               email = left(firstName,1) & lastNAme & domain
           Case Else
               email = left(firstName,1) & "." & lastNAme & domain
       End Select
    End Function

'use like this : Dave | cruz | = email("dave","cruz","firstlast") 

    Sub UpdateEmail()
         LastRow = sheet("name").Cells(sheet("name").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim format
        formatType = Application.InputBox("Set Email Format")
        Dim fqdn
        fqdn = Application.InputBox("Enter Email Domain", "Domain", Type:=2)
     dim c
    for each c in range( "A" & lastrow) 'your range
       c = email( c.offset(,-1),c.offset(,-2),"@" & fqdn, formatType)
     next 
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: "Select" is giving me a compile error. Just says "case"

Comment: Excellent. Apologies for my n00b status. How do I get it to write the data? Not terribly familiar with using functions. Added my input boxes above the function and am using 
email = firstName & lastName & fqdn

Comment: no use it like a formula, in a cell   insert your formula =email(A1;B1;"firstlast","@compagny.com")

Comment: you can also use it in vba : customEmail = email("dave","cruz","firstlast","@comp.com")

Comment: Need this to be automated. Inserting a formula into a cell defeats the purpose of a macro. I know the formulas to get the job done. Just looking to automate the process instead of inserting a formula and dragging it down 500 rows.

Comment: in you exemplae above, this is not automated because you will ask 500 times

Comment: Not true. It only asks once and uses the input as the variable.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot get it to work. At this point, I'm no closer to getting this to work. My original plan was to create a macro to perform this task. I have some minor issues with using rage with the ForumulaR1C1 and accepting an input variable. Once that works, then it's just a simple matter of adding in the rest of the IF Then statements and expanding the range to the whole document.

Comment: so it's not a coding problem , just type domain and option in one cell and then  add formula :  A1 = "compagny"      B1 ="firt" C1 ="last" D1= B1 & C1 & "@" & $A$1   D2 = left(B1;1) & C1 & "@" & $a$1 etc.    you're vba is just range("A1")= inputbox("compagny") good luck

Answer (score -1):

If I were you, I'd write a custom function for this:

```
Public Function FormatEmail(FirstName As String, LastName As String, Domain As String, Optional ByVal UseDot As Boolean = True) As String
    Dim Dot As String
    If UseDot Then
        Dot = "."
    Else
        Dot = ""
    End If
    FormatEmail = Left(FirstName, 1) & Dot & LastName & "@" & Domain
End Function
```

And then use it like this:

```
=FormatEmail("Bill","Gates","microsoft.com",0)

'returns BGates@microsoft.com

=FormatEmail("Bill","Gates","microsoft.com",1)

'returns B.Gates@microsoft.com
```

Comment: where is FirstLast@company.com